# Decoding path from ExactInput

Tags: python, binance-smart-chain

I have decoded the exactInput function, and got:

```
{'params': {'path': b"\xbbL\xdb\x9c\xbd6\xb0\x1b\xd1\xcb\xae\xbf-\xe0\x8d\x91s\xbc\t\\\x00\x01\xf4U\xd3\x982o\x99\x05\x9f\xf7uHRF\x99\x90'\xb3\x19yU",
  'recipient': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
  'amountIn': 10000000000000000,
  'amountOutMinimum': 0}}
```

I got it from pancake smart router
How can i decode the path now please?